# How do I convert scanner input into an integer?

Tags: java, int, java.util.scanner

In Java, how, if possible, can I convert numerical scanner input (such as 2 or 87) into an integer variable? What I'm using now yields the error message:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at diDecryption.Didecryption.main(Didecryption.java:226)
```

And this is the code I'm using to do it (pieced together, it's part of a much larger program):

```
    System.out.println("Enter first number");
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in); 
    String name=sc.next();
    int result = Integer.valueOf(name);
    if (result / 2 == 1){
    System.out.println("a");
```

The purpose of the program is to decode an encrypted message. The input is numerical, and if I remove the string to int converter, the division does not work. How do I fix this?

Comment: Your code works fine for me if I give it a number.  What, exactly, are you providing as input on system in? (The error message you've posted indicates you're trying to parse `null`)

Comment: What is your input ? The code looks fine to me. http://ideone.com/omNdEF

Comment: I doubt that your exception message matches your code. Scanner methods don't return `null`. They will throw an exception if there's nothing to read. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The steps given do not reproduce the quoted problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
package exmaple;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Parser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String name = in.next();

        try{
            int result = Integer.parseInt(name);
            if(result / 2 == 1) {
                System.out.println("a");
            }

        } catch(Exception exception) {

        }
        in.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
System.out.println("Enter first number");
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in); 
int name=sc.nextInt();
if ((name / 2) == 1)
System.out.println("a");
```

**RUN**

```
run:
Enter first number
2
a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Enter first number");
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in); 
String name=sc.next();
int result = Integer.parseInt(name);
if (result / 2 == 1){
System.out.println("a");
```

parseint changes it to a primitive int rather than an Integer object

Comment: That won't make any difference, Java's quite happy to unbox the `Integer` returned by `valueOf()`.

Answer (score 0):

In your stacktrace you have `null` as parameter in `Integer.valueOf(name)`. 
Seems your console produce some invalid input sequence.
Try to check it with `sc.hasNext()` condition:

```
    System.out.println("Enter first number");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (sc.hasNext()) {
        String name = sc.next();
        int result = Integer.parseInt(name);
        if (result / 2 == 1) {
            System.out.println("a");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
System.out.println("Enter first number");
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in); 
int result = sc.nextInt;
if (result / 2 == 1){
System.out.println("a");
```